# How can I add formatting within a cell that only applies to part of the cell value using EPPlus?

Tags: epplus

I know how to format cell values in EPPlus but only if the format applies to the whole value. How can I add formatting that only applies to *part* of the cell value?

for example...

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create multistyled cell with EPPlus library for Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973240/how-can-i-create-multistyled-cell-with-epplus-library-for-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `RichText` collection to build it:

```
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var wb = pck.Workbook;
    var ws = wb.Worksheets.First();

    var cell = ws.Cells["B2"];
    cell.RichText.Add("This is some ");
    cell.RichText.Add("formatting");
    cell.RichText.Add(" withing a value");

    cell.RichText[1].Color = Color.Red;
    cell.RichText[1].Size = 14;

    pck.Save();
}
```